# Python CSV Finding average time taken

Tags: python, csv, datetime, time, average

I am trying to find the average time taken. The value 'x' will allow me to get the time taken for every row there is, but how am I able to find the average time taken for all the rows. I will think it is something like x divided by count, but I am not able to find a solution to this... any pros out there can help me??

```
import datetime,time,csv
from itertools import islice
from Tkinter import Tk      #python GUI programming
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime
import pandas


Tk().withdraw()
category_list=[]
description_list=[]
reported_date=[]
acknowledged_date=[]
count = 0

# hard code all possible date formats
date_formats = ['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%-d-%b-%y', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%M %p', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M','%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M','%A %d %B %Y %H%M',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p"," %d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p", '%d-%b-%y' ,
                   '%d.%m.%Y', '%d %b %Y %H%M hrs', '%d %b %Y %H%M', '%d-%m-%y', '%d-%b-%y', '%b-%d-%y', '%d-%a-%y','%e-%a-%y','%b %d %Y %H%M hrs','%d/%b/%Y %m:%M %p','%A, %e %B %Y %H:%M',' %d/%m/%Y %h:%M','%d-%b-%y','%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p']
#file = askopenfilename() #ask user which file to open
#f = open(file,'r')
with open('Feedback and Complaints_Sample Dataset.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader) #read 2nd line onwards
    data= []  #make a list called data
    for row in reader: #assign data in every column and name them respectively


      for format in date_formats:
        try:

            reported_on = datetime.strptime(row[0], format) #try and get the dates
            acknowledged_on = datetime.strptime(row[12], format) #try and get the dates
            x= acknowledged_on-reported_on #time taken to acknowledge

            #acknowledged_date.append(acknowledged_on)
            #reported_date.append(reported_on)
            count += 1

            break # if correct format, dont test any other formats

        except ValueError:
            pass # if incorrect format, try other formats`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include some example lines from your CSV file, and the output you'd expect for them.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting two `datetime` objects creates a `timedelta` object. You need to keep a total time, so create a `timedelta` object, and for each `x` add it to your total.

At the end, you can then divide your `total_time` by your `count`:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


count = 0
total_time = timedelta()

# hard code all possible date formats
date_formats = ['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%-d-%b-%y', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%M %p', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M','%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M','%A %d %B %Y %H%M',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p"," %d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p", '%d-%b-%y' ,
                '%d.%m.%Y', '%d %b %Y %H%M hrs', '%d %b %Y %H%M', '%d-%m-%y', '%d-%b-%y', '%b-%d-%y', '%d-%a-%y','%e-%a-%y','%b %d %Y %H%M hrs','%d/%b/%Y %m:%M %p','%A, %e %B %Y %H:%M',' %d/%m/%Y %h:%M','%d-%b-%y','%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p']

with open('Feedback and Complaints_Sample Dataset.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader) #read 2nd line onwards

    for row in reader:
        for format in date_formats:
            try:
                reported_on = datetime.strptime(row[0], format) #try and get the dates
                acknowledged_on = datetime.strptime(row[12], format) #try and get the dates
                x = acknowledged_on - reported_on #time taken to acknowledge
                total_time += x
                count += 1
                break # if correct format, don't test any other formats

            except ValueError:
                pass # if incorrect format, try other formats`enter code here`

print "Total time taken:", total_time                
print "Average time taken:", total_time / count
```

Note: your logic for the `date_formats` implies that both dates in a single row will always share the same date format.